# How to check if any cells in excel matches any other cell

Tags: excel

I have several excel files with a single column with thousands of rows with a time in each cell. I'm using them further in another program, but there are some errors in them. In some of the files there are two or more times matching each other, which corrupts my further progress.

*I need to see if any cell matches any other cell in the entire spreadsheet. I need to delete any duplicates.*

Does anyone need how to do that? I found ways to check column by column, but that's not what i want.

Thanks for all your help!

Magnus
Norway

Comment: Go to Data tab and select "Remove duplicates" and then follow wizard instructions.  This will DELETE The duplicates!

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of work. I obviously thought of the problem more complicated than it was...

Comment: Well, I was a bit confused.  In one case you say you have a single column with thousands of rows containing a time, and then you say any other cell in the entire spreadsheet... so I took a stab at your first statement being accurate and using embedded excel functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write some code to get all data from all of yours worksheet together and then clean your data. You can write a VBA script or use Power Query. Please give me some more detail so i will able to elaborate or give you the final solution.